# How to find distinct elements in a comma seperated line of string?

Tags: google-bigquery

I like to find distinct elements and order them in a line of string, which is separated by comma using standard SQL(BigQuery).

I already have a String like:

> B,A,A,D,C,B

I like to generate:

> A,B,C,D

I have tried using **STRING_AGG** function.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT split(str,","), "," ORDER BY str ASC )  AS string_agg
FROM  UNNEST ( [(select f0_ from temp3 )]) AS str
```

I get the error:

> "No matching signature for aggregate function STRING_AGG for argument
>   types: ARRAY, STRING"

Any suggestion for using other functions or a change in structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION STRING_DEDUP(str STRING) AS (
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(item ORDER BY item) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT item FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str)) item 
  ))  
);
SELECT 
  STRING_DEDUP(str) `string_agg`
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION STRING_DEDUP(str STRING) AS (
  (SELECT STRING_AGG(item ORDER BY item) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT item FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(str)) item 
  ))  
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'B,A,A,D,C,B' str UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X,X,Z,Y,Y'
)
SELECT 
  STRING_DEDUP(str) `string_agg`
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row string_agg   
1   A,B,C,D  
2   X,Y,Z
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split` function is a good idea. It returns an array of strings which you can sort and remove duplicates from it. Finally if you want an string output you can use `ARRAY_TOSTRING` function.

Putting it altogether, running this query:

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(
    ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT x FROM UNNEST(split('b,a,a,b,d,c')) AS x ORDER BY x),
    ','
)
```

gives the desired result.